# PHP reference to his own? Dynamic HTML Output?

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I am just trying to build my first own Wordpress Theme. Everythings fine as far, but now i am doing the Settings Page for the WP Backend and i here i got a problem inside the functions.php:
There is a Slider on the Page, and i have a  where you can enter how much Images you want to have on them. Now i want that every time i change this input the number of inputs for the image links changes. So when there is a 2 in the input there shall be 2 more iputs for the URL of the images.

I got this so far:

```
function theme_front_page_settings() {
  if (!current_user_can('manage_options')) {
    wp_die('You do not have sufficient permissions to access this page.');
  }
?>  
  <form action="this" method="post">
    <label for="num_carousel">Number of Carousel Screens:</label> 
    <input type="number" id="num_carousel" name="num_carousel" value="3" min="1" max="5" oninput="fieldsNum()"/> 
  </form> 
<?php

  for($count = 1; $count < $_POST['num_carousel']; $count++){
    echo "<label for='num_carousel".$count."'>Carousel Screen</label><input type='text' name='num_carousel".$count."'/><br>";
  }
}
```

Is this the right way? In line 6 I set the action to "this", because i didn`t know how I should reference to the own script. How do I have to do this? Is this possible anyway ?

Hope that you can help me.
Black Phantom

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're doing it the right way.

The idiomatic way to handle the form action, is "#" instead of "this".